# How to write Text in custom Paint using Paint() in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to write text above a widget which have parameter paint which takes Paint(). This widget draws edges between graph nodes and it does not take any parameter as TextPaint().

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBQ6S.png)

Comment: so you have a `CustomPainter` and want to draw some text inside?

Comment: @pskink Yes Custom Paint has a constructor Paint() which draws a line. I want to write text above that line as no other parameters other than paint are given to customize widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example for drawing a text inside a CustomPainter or a CustomDecoration. All you need is to use a TextPainter on the canvas.

```
final textPainter = TextPainter(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Foo\nBar',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 30,
    ),
  ),
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center
);
textPainter.layout();

// Draw the text centered around the point (50, 100) for instance
final offset = Offset(50 - (textPainter.width / 2), 100 - (textPainter.height / 2));
textPainter.paint(canvas, offset);
```